# What are the origins of the Displacer Beast?

Tags: monsters, dungeons-and-dragons, content-identification

The *displacer beast* is one of the game's iconic monsters. But it does not seem to come from the same kind of medieval bestiary like the [gorgon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111271/why-is-the-dd-gorgon-a-metal-bull/196362#196362), or from cheap plastic toys like the [owlbear or bulette](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/34825/whats-the-inspiration-for-the-owlbear).

[image]

I've seen claims that the monster was vaguely inspired by a PJ Farmer critter in his "Created Universes" series, or that it came from A. E. van Vogt's *Voyage of the Space Beagle*.

Does anybody know what its literary (or other) origin is?

Comment: Related on [how one appears wearing a cloak of displacement](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/103366/23970) where my answer goes into a bit of the lore-history of displacer beasts. (As opposed to the game-history, which QW has below.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### It was inspired by a creature called the coeurl.

You are correct: it was inspired by the *coeurl*, from [A. E. van Vogt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._E._van_Vogt)'s 1939 science fiction story [Black Destroyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Destroyer), which was later made into the first six chapters of his 1950 novel [The Voyage of the Space Beagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Voyage_of_the_Space_Beagle) (1950).

From the word of Gary Gygax himself, dated [January 26, 2005](https://ridureyu.tripod.com/ggygax.html):

> [...] the Displacer beasts I ripped off from the novel, Voyage of the Spaceship Beagle...if I recall rightly. That was one of the monsters in there - they sucked out something from humans with their tentacles, I don't remember!"

From the description, he can only be referring to the coeurl, the antagonist of *Black Destroyer*, which absorbs phosphorous (in the novel, potassium) from living beings. It is also described as having the ability to control vibrations, which the AD&D 1e *Monster Manual* describes is the origin of the displacer beast's displacement ability. To quote Wikipedia's summary of *Black Destroyer*:

> A Coeurl, **a large, intelligent, black cat-like animal**, considers its near-future starvation as its food source of id-creatures has been hunted to extinction. [...] They lock him up, but the Coeurl's **ability to control "vibrations of every description"** allows him to easily open the electric lock.

And as per Wikipedia's summary of *The Voyage of the Space Beagle*:

> Coeurl, a starving, intelligent and **vicious cat-like carnivore with tentacles on its shoulders**, approaches the ship, pretending to be an unintelligent animal, and quickly infiltrates it.

Gygax also confirmed the work as the displacer beast's inspiration in a forum post on [February 12, 2005](https://www.enworld.org/threads/q-a-with-gary-gygax.22566/post-2029684):

> Q: *Was the displacer beast inspired by the Couatl* [sic] *in Van Vogt's "Voyage of the Black Destroyer"?*
>
> A: It was Van Vogt's Voyage of the Space Beagle when i read it...but I suspect the story is the same, yes :D

[August 2, 2007](https://www.enworld.org/threads/q-a-with-gary-gygax.22566/post-3675817):

> The displacer beast was most assuredly inspired by A. E. van Vogt's Voyage of the Space Beagle.

Gygax previously suggested it may have been inspired by a creature from [P. J. Farmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Jos%C3%A9_Farmer)'s [World of Tiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Tiers) science fiction series, which at the time the displacer beast was published (1977) consisted of the novels *The Maker of Universes* (1965), *The Gates of Creation* (1966), *A Private Cosmos* (1968), *Behind the Walls of Terra* (1970), and possibly *The Lavalite World* (1977). [March 10, 2003](https://www.enworld.org/threads/q-a-with-gary-gygax.22566/post-756734):

> Displacer Beast--Vaguely inspired by a PJ Farmer critter in his "Created Universes" series, but not drawn from any specific thing therein.

However, it's possible he was mis-remembering in this instance.